# Get Account management - Display Name - Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This little piece of code gets the system current logged in user's Display name

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Dim userFullName As String = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
Label1.Text = "Hi " & userFullName & ", Welcome !!"
```

The above code works fine when i connected the LAN to the computer.  but when LAN is  removed and WIFI is connected it doesn't work .. Can someone guide the workaround for this?

Comment: This only works as long as the directory server can be contacted. I guess via WIFI the directory server isn't reachable.

Comment: Any workaround that i can get the displayname without connecting to LAN ?

Answer (score 0):

This method only works as long as the directory server can be contacted.

Otherwise you get a `PrincipalServerDownException`.

As a workaround you could cache the displayname while the server is reachable.

You can cache it for example inside `My.Settings`.

Create a user scoped setting named `cachedDisplayname` and use the following method:

```
Function GetUserDisplayName() As String
    Dim userFullName As String

    Try
        'Reading the displayname from the directory
        userFullName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
        'Saving the displayname in My.Settings
        My.Settings.cachedDisplayname = userFullName
        My.Settings.Save()
    Catch ex As PrincipalServerDownException
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(My.Settings.cachedDisplayname) Then
            'displayname has not been cached yet, use Username as compromise solution
            userFullName = Environment.UserName
        Else
            'read the cached displayname from My.Settings
            userFullName = My.Settings.cachedDisplayname
        End If
    End Try

    Return userFullName
End Function
```

Setting the label-text:

```
Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}, Welcome !!", GetUserDisplayName())
```